# Razor filter dropdown not filtering when selecting a projects

Tags: c#, .net, razor, model-view-controller

Hello I have a page that has two filters that are quite the same but one of them is not working right and I am not sure what is wrong with my code!

[image of the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9lIB.png)

Thank you in advance!

Here is my code in the view :

> @Html.DropDownList("Projects", (SelectList)ViewBag.Projects, "Please Select a Project...",
>   htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

here is the code in my controller :

```
    public ActionResult Index(string projects, int? EmployeeId)

    {
        var status = db.Projects.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = 
m.ProjectName.ToString(), Text = m.ProjectName }).Distinct().ToList();


        ViewBag.Projects = new SelectList(status, "Value", "Text");

        ViewBag.EmployeeId = db.Employees.Select(p => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
            Value = p.ID.ToString()
        });


        var employee = db.EmployeeTimesheets.Where(student => student.Projects != null);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(projects))
        {
            employee = employee.Where(student => student.Projects == projects);
        }

        if (EmployeeId > 0)
        {
            employee = employee.Where(student => student.EmployeeId == EmployeeId);
        }

        return View(employee);
    }
```

Comment: what is not working

Comment: in the dropdown projects, when I select a project it does not filter

Comment: do you have any code that executes the filter when the project is selected? ie javascript or an action?

Comment: I just edited the question with the view! @Ric

Comment: so basically, no post to the server is occurring?  you need to wrap the filters in a form, post to the server and handle the filtering there

Comment: I did the exact same thing with the filter employee and it is working... but the projects is basically the same but not working so I think that the problem is in the controller